# Transparent View at the Top of a UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiview

When you open Mail on an iPhone and tap Edit, select an email and tap Move, a `UITableView` appears with all the folders you can put the mail in. At the top is a transparent view that shows the email you selected. When you move your finger down, the view stays in place, when you move it up, the cells are visible through the transparent view.

How did apple configure this view? I thought of two ways, but they both don't work:

- The view is returned as the *header view* of the `UITableView`. Doesn't work because the view stays at the top even if the table view is moved down.
- The view is static at the top, the frame of the table view starts at the bottom of the transparent view. This doesn't work because when the table view is moved up, it is visible through the transparent view.

Any ideas on how to recreate this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your transparent view and then add it as a subview to the view controller so it's a sibling of the `UITableView`. You would do this in the `viewDidLoad()` method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    int viewHeight = 50;

    // Assume myTableView is a UITableView variable
    myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 44) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    myTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(viewHeight, 0, 0, 0);
    myTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(viewHeight, 0, 0, 0);

    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,viewHeight)]; 

    // Configure your view here.
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.7 blue:0.8 alpha:0.75];

    [self.view addSubview:myTableView];
    [self.view addSubview:myView];
    [myView release];

}
```

You could also setup your view using an XIB, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

**Edit:** Removed the requirement for the the `UITableView` delegate methods and custom header view by using the `contentInset` property instead.

**Note:** see additional comments below.

Comment: I've just been testing this out in one of my own apps and it looks like you can't use this within a `UITableViewController`. I was able to get it to work by using a `UIViewController` and adding 2 subviews, a `UITableView`, and then the transparent `UIView`.

Comment: You actually can add it, if you replace `self.view` with `self.someTableView`, but the view will just be static within the table view and move with it.

Comment: Correct. That's exactly the behaviour I found. I assumed you wanted it fixed at the top.

Comment: I would like it to be fixed at the top of the view controller, so that it does not scroll. You can open the Mail app on your iOS device and see it in action :)

Comment: Ok. Well it works for me if you follow my first comment i.e. use a `UIViewController` and add your `UIView` and `UITableView` to it as subviews. It's actually quite a nice effect. Might use it myself :D

Comment: But isn't the first cell always behind the view? How did you set the frames?

Comment: Ah I didn't think about the first cell. I'll look into this now.

Comment: Ok I've updated the code above. Basically you need to return an empty UIView for the header and also return the height of the header view. Also the scrollbar insets need to be offset to account for the height of your transparent view.

Comment: Well, that `scrollIndicatorInsets` is amazing! Your code is perfect, just note that you get a leak when creating the header view (`[[UIView alloc] init]`). I declared it as an instance variable and only allocated memory once in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: yes creating the instance variable is the way to go or use autorelease. If you're switching to this mode just like in the Mail app then creating it on the fly might be better. BTW - Thanks for the accept.

Comment: Just been reading the `UIScrollView` class reference and you might be able to just use the `contentOffset` property instead of setting a custom header view. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentOffset

Comment: @Ben Have you tried it? For me, it doesn't work. I think this property is automatically set by the scrollview/tableview when it is scrolled

Comment: @fabian789 I hadn't at the time, but yes you are correct but I did find a better solution. I've updated the code above.

Answer (score -1):

For the XIB method:

- Create a new UIViewController (with XIB)
- Add to it your UITableView and your UIView.
- Make them both subviews of the default UIView (called View) and make sure that they are added in the correct order. UITableView should be the first in the list, your view should be second (so your view is on top of the UITableView).
- In the .m file implement the minimum for UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate:

  -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;

  -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;

  -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

  -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- In Interface Builder select the UITableView list and go to 'Connection Inspector'. There drag dataSource and delegate to 'File Owner'.

Save and run. You should be done now.