# iOS: Adding a fixed image just below the navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios, image, uitableview, frontend

It feels like this should be fairly simple but nothing i've tried so far has worked. In a nutshell, I want to add a fixed image just below the navigation bar in a UITableViewController that i create programmatically. In other words, I want the image to stay just below the navigation bar even as the user scrolls up and down the table view (it's basically a custom drop-shadow for the navigation bar).

The closest I've gotten is the code below (in the UITableViewController's init method), which adds the image but doesn't keep it from moving when the user scrolls.

```
// Add nav bar drop shadow
UIImage *dropShadowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBarDropShadow.png"];
UIImageView *dropShadowView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:dropShadowImage];
[self.view addSubview:dropShadowView];
```

Is there an easy way to add an add an image to the screen programmatically, position it wherever you like, and have it stay there even as the user scrolls? Thanks for any and all input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: IOS5 has a better way to do this. Please check out the new [UIAppearance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol.

Adding this block of code to your code will allow you to draw your shadow on all UINavigationBars in the app. This is a better solution than adding the shadow as a UIImageView:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (ShadowBar)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    //draw the shadow ui nav bar
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"UINavBarWithShadow.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 300);
}
@end
```

To make the UINavigationBar higher and thus not clipping your content, override the `layoutSubviews` and set the frame you need (the code above assumes your header is 300 points high). `layoutSubviews` does nothing by default, but is "lazy" called before lay-outing the view.

For more info about this custom size/look overrides that apply to UIView (and any other subclass) have a look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-DontLinkElementID_3)

Comment: This is a great sample, although I'd add it in a separate file.

Comment: This seems to be really close to working. The drop shadow needs to come down below where the navigation bar usually gets cut off. I've got this line `[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height + 15.5)];` which gives my new navigation bar image the right aspect ratio, but the drop shadow is cut off. Is there a way to make the "overflow" from the navigation bar visible?

Comment: See the addition to my answer please

Comment: Thanks for your help mindnoise (and everyone else). I fixed this particular problem using some slight modifications to your suggestion, but it gave rise to a new interesting question. I've asked it separately at http://stackoverflow.com/q/6169474/622981 .

Answer (score 2):

You can make a subclass or a category on UINavigationBar, and have it add the image in the `init` or `drawRect` methods. If you think about it, you're trying to add a shadow to the navigation bar, not to the UITableView, so it makes sense to modify the navbar, not the table.

Comment: that would be a subclass rather than a category.

Comment: a category is preferred in my opinion, the change is too small for a subclass and no functionality is changed...

Comment: I've left it at both, since I see a stylistic difference has come to light.

Comment: aren't categories for adding methods, rather than overriding methods?

Comment: @GradyPlayer - Yes, that is correct, but it's a matter of taste, I think. I'll leave the decision up to you.

Comment: True, I know Apple says that, but this is a situation where, in my opinion, I think we can break that rule just for the sake of simplicity

Comment: but UINavigationController already has a drawRect: and and init method. I don't know if you can even add it with a category, and if you could, which would be called, they certainly wouldn't both be called.

Comment: @GradyPlayer - You can add them, just call the `super` methods inside them. I believe it's the `drawRect` method, but I'm not certain.

Comment: but that will be the superclass of UINavigationController, and wouldn't perform any functionality that the UINavigationController's methods would perform, even if it works now, it may not in the future.

Comment: you can do it with a category, check out the code in my post. As for the one that gets called, it's only your method (and there is no way you can call the "super" method) that's one of the reason categories are not traditionally used to extend and rather to add. but in this specific situation, it works just fine.

Comment: @Moshe, you sure you can call `super` in a category? I don't think you can, but, it could be, I can't remember right now.

Comment: @GradyPlayer - Incorrect, my good sir. All Cocoa object's must be initialized, through the `init` method. `drawRect` is called on the `UINavigationBar`. I know because I've used it in the past. Again, make sure to call `super`!

Comment: you are potentially adding a bug, one that will be very hard to find in the future, like... why doesn't some new control element in my UINavigationBar work anymore.

Comment: @mindnoise - Fairly certain you can. I did it in my app. (Okay, an upcoming update, but it works.)

Comment: @GradyPlayer, It has nothing to do with `UINavigationController`, more likely with `UINavigationBar`

Comment: @GradyPlayer - Because Apple broke it, not because I did anything wrong. Calling `super` in a category is the same thing as calling it in a subclass. The only difference is that a category affects all instances of a class throughout an application, but it is implied. A subclass must be specifically instantiated as a subclass and you can have multiple subclasses side-by-side.

Comment: @Moshe, just tried to call super, and it does work. Try this code:`@implementation UINavigationBar (ShadowBar)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    //draw the shadow ui nav bar
    //UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"UINavBarWithShadow.png"];
    //[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    [super drawRect:rect];
}
@end`

Comment: @moshe... good times, I like the "Because Apple broke it" but calling [super method] in a category isn't the same as calling [super method] in a subclass. you could swizzle out [self method] if you wanted to be correct... it probably doesn't do anything... but that doesn't mean that it can't, or doesn't... or won't.

Comment: @GradyPlayer - How is it different?

Comment: yes calling [super method] in a category isn't the same as calling [super method] in a subclass....Agree on that.

Comment: because in a category you aren't making a subclass and super!=self

Comment: Actually, I think that's a good question, so I've [asked it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168058/is-calling-super-in-a-category-the-same-as-calling-it-in-a-subclass).

Comment: @Moshe, a category 'replaces' the method at runtime and a subclass 'extends' it (meaning that it still has a reference to the old method via `super'.....try the code above

Comment: Will move the discussion there then :)

Comment: All be damned self does equal super... carry on.

Comment: @GradyPlayer - Instead of damning everyone, how about giving an academic answer to an academic question?

Comment: @GradyPlayer , @mindnoise thanks for startibg this discussio, btw. Seems like my other question is doing quite well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding your dropShadowView to self.view that in your case is the view of an UITableViewController. It means that your self.view is an UITableView so when you scroll up and down you scroll the dropShadowView as well because is inside the tableView.

Try to write a custom UIViewController and add two subviews: one is the dropShadowView and the other one is your table.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this similar question I answered a while back. It should do exactly what you want with little customization.

[Transparent View at the Top of a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753218/transparent-view-at-the-top-of-a-uitableview/5753417#5753417)

Answer (score 0):

Dont make a `UITableView` the main view ie. the `view` outlet, set that to a `UIView` that contains a `UITableView`, then make your controller a subclass of `UIViewController`, and make it conform to `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`. in your nib, set up your view so that you have a UIImageView at the top and a UITableView below. and set the `delegate` and `datasource` to your `file's owner`.