# Is calling super in a category the same as calling it in a subclass?

Tags: objective-c, subclass, categories

Does calling `[super init]` do the same thing in a category as a subclass? If not, what's the difference?

Comment: "When a category overrides an inherited method, the method in the category can, as usual, invoke the inherited implementation via a message to super. However, if a category overrides a method that exists in the category's class, there is no way to invoke the original implementation." from [How you can use categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-TPXREF141).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to understand this, it's probably important to understand the way an object is stored during runtime. There is a class object<sup>1</sup>, which holds all the method implementations, and separately, there is a structure with the storage for the instance's variables. All instances of a class share the one class object.

When you call a method on an instance, the compiler turns that into a call to [`objc_msgSend`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-objc_msgSend); the method implementation is looked up in the class object, and then run with the instance as an argument.

A reference to `super` takes effect at compile time, *not* run time. When you write `[super someMethod]`, the compiler turns that into a call to [`objc_msgSendSuper`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-objc_msgSendSuper) instead of the usual `objc_msgSend`. This starts looking for the method implementation in the *superclass's* class object, rather than the instance's class object.<sup>2</sup>

A category simply adds methods to the class object; it has little or no relation to subclassing.

Given all that, if you refer to `super` inside of a category, it does indeed do the same thing that it would inside of a class -- the method implementation is looked up on the class object of the *superclass*, and then run with that instance as an argument.

Itai's post answers the question more directly, but in code:

```
@interface Sooper : NSObject {}
- (void) meth;
@end

@interface Sooper ()
- (void) catMeth;
@end

@interface Subb : Sooper {}
- (void) subbMeth;
@end

@interface Subb ()
- (void) catSubbMeth;
@end

@implementation Sooper
- (void) meth {
    [super doIt];    // Looks up doIt in NSObject class object
}

- (void) catMeth {
    [super doIt];    // Looks up doIt in NSObject class object
}
@end

@implementation Subb
- (void) subbMeth {
    [super doIt];    // Looks up doIt in Sooper class object
}

- (void) catSubbMeth {
    [super doIt];    // Looks up doIt in Sooper class object
}
@end
```

---

<sup>1</sup> See Greg Parker's writeup [[objc explain]: Classes and meta-classes](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/04/14/objc_explain_Classes_and_metaclasses.html)

<sup>2</sup>One important thing to note is that the method doesn't get called on an *instance* of the superclass. This is where that separation of methods and data comes in. The method still gets called on the same instance in which `[super someMethod]` was written, i.e., an instance of the subclass, using that instance's data; it just uses the superclass's implementation of the method.

So a call to `[super class]` goes to the superclass object, finds the implementation of the method named `class`, and calls it on the instance, transforming it into the equivalent of `[self theSuperclassImplementationOfTheMethodNamedClass]`. Since all that method does is return the class of the instance *on which it was called*, you don't get the superclass's class, you get the class of `self`. Due to that, calling `class` is kind of a poor test of this phenomenon.

<sub>This whole answer completely ignores the message-passing/method call distinction. This is an important feature of ObjC, but I think that it would probably just muddy an already awkward explanation.</sub>

Comment: so is this because the data for -class is stored in the subclasses instance data? rather than something like [[self class] classMethodforClass], then why does [[super class]class] still use that instance data, shouldn't it be a class method of the superclass.

Comment: If you call a method by referring to either `self` or `super`, it is passed the current instance's data, yes. The only difference is which implementation of the method is used. If you call `[self doSomething]` and the current class hasn't re-implemented `doSomething`, then that is equivalent to `[super doSomething]`. The only reason to use `super` is when you specifically need to call the superclass's implementation, usually from within the overridden method.

Comment: Saying `[obj class]` gives you an object of type `Class *`, but that object's class is _itself_, so `[obj class] == [[obj class] class]`

Comment: how does [[obj class] class] have instance data? I mean to say the complier wont let me access ivar info from a class method. if it does then how does it know what instance to use?

Comment: @Grady: because a `Class` object is also an Objective-C object. Take a look at [<objc/runtime.h>](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437.1/runtime/runtime.h); search for "struct objc_class". Then see [<objc/objc.h>](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437.1/runtime/objc.h): `typedef struct objc_class * Class`. The `Class` object has an `isa` pointer just like other objects. You can't access ivars from a `+` class method because there is no ivar storage in the `Class` object, only method implementations.

Comment: but in Object.m +class is defined as + class 
{
    return self;
}and -class is defined as - class
{
 return (id)isa; 
}
so by calling [[super class] class] i should be getting the class object of the superclass.

Comment: No: `[super class]` turns into something along the lines of: `objc_msgSendSuper(mySuperClassStruct, @selector(class))`, where `mySuperClassStruct` is an [`objc_super`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH3g-BBCFBBGA) struct, which contains a pointer to `self` and to the `Class` object. The function looks up the implementation of `class` in the superclass object, and then essentially does `objc_msgSend(self, IMPFromSuper);` -- the method is still called on `self`.

Comment: Or, we could say: `[super class]` uses the `-` instance method, and returns a `Class` object, the `isa` of the instance. Calling `class` on the result uses the `+` class method, which returns the `self` of the `Class` object.

Answer (score 8):

No, they do different things. Imagine a class structure like this: `NSObject` => `MyObject` => `MySubclass`, and say you have a category on `MyObject` called `MyCategory`.

Now, calling from `MyCategory` is akin to calling from `MyObject`, and therefore `super` points to `NSObject`, and calling `[super init]` invokes `NSObject`'s `-init` method. However, calling from the subclass, `super` points to `MyObject`, so initializing using `super` invokes `MyObject`'s `-init` method, which, unless it isn't overridden, behaves differently from `NSObject`'s.

These two behaviors are different, so be careful when initializing using categories; categories are not subclasses, but rather additions to the current class.

Comment: This is the correct answer. For bonus points, look into [supersequent](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/supersequent-implementation.html) implementations in Objective-C.

Comment: +1: This does answer the question more directly than my answer (I think I misinterpreted the question, in fact). One nit that I can pick, however, is that `super` doesn't really _point_ to anything. It's not itself an object, but a compile-time construct.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Your answer is much easier to understand! :)

Answer (score 2):

Given the below example, `super` will call `UIView` init (not `UINavigationBar` init method)

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (ShadowBar)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    //draw the shadow ui nav bar
    [super init];
}
@end
```

If you subclass it, `[super init]` will call `UINavigationBar` init method.

So yes, if there are additional things you will do in `UINavigationBar` init (extra from UIView) they do different things.

Comment: totally what I thought, but turns out not to be the case, super is still navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: the following is built on a flawed premise, please look at josh's answer.

not deleting, still an interesting reference for something that could potentially lead you astray.

They are the same thing... without referencing any outside dicussions we may have had where you stated that I should ..."answer an academic question with an academic answer"

```
@implementation categoryTestViewController (ShadowBar)
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    //draw the shadow ui nav bar
    NSLog(@"super's class = %@, self's class %@",[super class],[self class]);
    if ([self class] == [super class]) {
        NSLog(@"yeah they are the same");
    }
}
@end
```

outputs:

```
2011-05-29 08:06:16.198 categoryTest[9833:207] super's class = categoryTestViewController, self's class categoryTestViewController
2011-05-29 08:06:16.201 categoryTest[9833:207] yeah they are the same
```

and calling the [super viewDidAppear:] will result in calling nothing... not a loop, so I don't know what it is really doing there.

Comment: I thought that this would be the result. I suspect that a category is essentially a compiler-enforced subclass at runtime.

Comment: I did some testing on osx and in the terminal it says now that the old method is an unrecognized signature, so I guess it is just swizzled away.

Comment: Wait, I have to check something, what does `[self class] == [super class]` do? what does it tests?

Comment: I gotta run now, I'd love to see the outcome of these experiments when I get back. Feel free to test cases and their results.

Comment: Yeah that beats me too.. [super superclass] would give you access to class methods...

Comment: `[self isKindOfClass:[categoryTestViewController class]` retruns the same thing, so I guess this is correct, however, I still don't know WHY calling [`super viewDidAppear:]` has no effect, any clues?

Comment: no, but here is an even stranger fact, calling [self sameMethod] does cause a loop.

Comment: Calling `[super class]` doesn't actually give you the class of the superclass; it will always give you the class object of the current instance. This is explained in my answer. Use `[self superclass]` to get the superclass's class object. @mindnoise