# How to inspect 'super' when debugging objc in gdb

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xcode4, gdb

From within xcode, gdb gives the following:

```
> po self
<SomeClassName: 0x6672e50>
```

So far so good... But:

```
> po super
No symbol "super" in current context.
```

In the interest of clarity, what I really want to do is send a message to `super` while debugging. For example, I want to do something like this:

```
> po [super doSomething]
```

But how do I reference `super` from within the gdb environment? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Hey, we were [just talking about this!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168058/is-calling-super-in-a-category-the-same-as-calling-it-in-a-subclass/6170660#6170660) The word `super` doesn't have any effect except as the receiver of a message, i.e., `[super doSomething]`. It's just a note to the compiler that it should search for the implementation of a method in the superclass rather than the current class object.

If you want an object's actual superclass object, use the `NSObject` protocol's [`superclass` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCDIACA): `[self superclass]`.

---

I don't know how to do exactly what you want. How about a debugger hook? Put this into your class:

```
- (void) callSupersDoSomething {
    [super doSomething];
}
```

and then you can call `[self callSupersDoSomething]` from the debugger.

Comment: wouldn't that return a Class object as opposed to a reference to super? So in my example above, in gdb: `po [self superclass]` returns: `SomeClassName`, instead of the required: `<SomeClassName: 0x1234a12>`

Comment: @Jim: There's no such thing as "a reference to super." There's a reference to the current object in `self`, and you can get a reference to the superclass with `[self superclass]`, but there is no actual thing in your program called "super." It's a keyword that causes the message to be sent to `self` but will skip the current class's methods when resolving the message.

Comment: Chuck's comment is much clearer than mine was, but @Jim, what are you looking for by getting at the superclass?

Comment: well what I'm trying to do is just send a message to super from gdb: `po [super doSomething]`. The problem is that gdb responds with `No symbol "super" in current context.`

Comment: @Jim: Got it. Interesting question. I don't know, but I've added a suggestion to my answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing at the moment but was wondering if I could avoid the hack. Thanks for giving it a shot anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Something to keep in mind here, is that `super == self`.  It's the same object pointer, but the `super` keyword tells the message dispatch code to start looking for an implementation one level back in the class hierarchy.

Comment: Great, what I'm trying to figure out is how to do the same in gdb. That is, send a message to self but use the implementation one level back in the class hierarchy. In code it's as simple as `[super doSomething]`, but if I type that in gdb I get `No symbol "super" in current context.` I'm trying to figure out the gdb equivalent.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?   You could go through the trouble of executing objc_msgSendSuper() in the debugger, but I've never had occasion to do that in all the years I've been writing Obj-C code.

Comment: Just wonna send a message to super while debugging, I have a few good reasons, too long of a use case to explain here. Thanks.

Comment: Well, here's one really hacky suggestion.  Change self->isa to point to [self superclass], send the message in question, and then change it back.