# Selector Sent to method overridden in Category fails

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, categories

I am trying to override a UIStoryboard method using a category. Here is my implementation:

```
#import "UIStoryboard+SomeCategory.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@implementation UIStoryboard(SomeCategory)

-(id)instantiateInitialViewController
{
    NSLog(@"SUPER CLASS: %@", [super class]); // logs "UIStoryboard"
    NSLog(@"SUPER RTS  : %@", [super respondsToSelector:@selector(instantiateInitialViewController)] ? @"YES" : @"NO"); // logs "YES"
    return [super instantiateInitialViewController];
}

@end
```

when I add:

```
 UIViewController *viewController = [super instantiateInitialViewController]
```

Why do I get the compiler error:

```
Receiver type 'NSObject' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'instantiateViewController'
```

Comment: `[super class]` [doesn't do what you think it does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168058/is-calling-super-in-a-category-the-same-as-calling-it-in-a-subclass/6170660#6170660) -- it returns the class of the current object, because it's using the method named `class` whose implementation is in the superclass, but the current instance as an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should note that `[super class]` is not the same as `[self superclass]`. Quoting the docs:

*Objective-C provides two terms that can be used within a method definition to refer to the object that performs the method—self and super.*

They differ in how the compiler will search for the method implementation, and in some cases they will mean just the same.

In this case you want:

```
NSLog(@"SUPER CLASS: %@", [self superclass]); // logs "NSObject"
```

to check an object's super class class, and you'll need a UIStoryBoard subclass, not a category, to be able to use:

```
return [super instantiateInitialViewController];
```

Why `[super class]` doesn't log what you expect is another subject. If you're interested, this post [What is a meta-class in Objective-C?](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `super` when overriding methods using a category, the method will be called on the superclass of the object, not the object you are overriding the method on. **You haven't made a subclass of `UIStoryboard`**, so `super` refers to `NSObject` - which is reflected accurately in your error message.

I don't know what's going on with your log messages, though.

Using a category to override a method means that you can't call the original method. You'll need to either make a subclass of `UIStoryboard` or an entirely new method in the category, that calls `[self instantiateInitialViewController]`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am handcuffed. I want to have UIStoryboard perform a selector on every UIViewController it instantiates, however there is nowhere I can insert a subclass of UIStoryboard into the application. UIStoryboard is created in a private method of UIApplication. It is no use creating a new method which then calls the original method because the framework uses the methods defined in UIStoryboard and would bypass any new method. Don't suppose you have any ideas?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but you should ask that as a separate question, I think it will get a good response.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use method swizzling.  good explanation of how to use it for your purposes here: http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/method-swizzling-to-override-in-a-category

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to call that method from a UIViewController, your category should be:

```
@implementation UIViewController(SomeCategory)
```

Even so, it would call the super of your UIViewController, so it would still not work. You also need to do the following:

```
 UIViewController *viewController = [self instantiateInitialViewController]
```

Comment: I think you've misread the question, 1ndivisible is trying to use a category to override a method in UIStoryboard, and to call the original implementation of that method using `super`

Comment: Humm, you are right jrturton. I was confused with the way he was instantiating the UIViewController.