# Subclass VS Category for CALayer

Tags: objective-c, subclass, calayer, categories

If I subclass a `CALayer` and override the `drawInContext:` method everything is great. If I create a category for `CALayer` where I override the same method (as an alternative to subclassing), it gets called but it doesn't draw anything. Of course, the `[super drawInContext:ctx]` is called in both cases. Why? 
I have no problem with subclassing, I'm just curious as to why this happens. I was under the impression that categories could be used to add or override methods for any class, as an alternative to creating a whole subclass. 
Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selector Sent to method overridden in Category fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891822/selector-sent-to-method-overridden-in-category-fails)

Comment: Basically, calling super implementations in a category calls them on the superclass of the object you have the category against, not the original object implementation which is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Oh, I see, I thought I read somewhere that calling [super] in an overridden method inside a category called the original method, it sounded strange but I rolled with it. I was wrong :)

Comment: So is there a way to do just that, call the original method?

Comment: Not from a category, that I know of. I'm sure there's some magical scary method of doing so, but it's beyond me.

Comment: Thanks! You should mark your comment as an answer!

Comment: OK, I wouldn't normally as this is a dupe, but the dupe I linked to does go off on a bit of a tangent, so there you go.

Comment: @jrturton: Indeed, the magical scary method is called ["swizzling"](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MethodSwizzling).

Comment: @JoshCaswell - see, now you've gone and scared me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling the `super` implementation in a category calls them on the superclass of the object you have the category against, not the original object implementation which is what you are trying to do.

`super`, when used in the context of a method call in an instance method, calls the superclass's implementation of that method.

In a category, *you haven't made a subclass* - the code you have written is being executed directly by the class you have the category against. Therefore calls to `super` implementations will be sent to `CALayer`'s superclass, which is `NSObject`.

I'm therefore a little surprised that you didn't get compiler warnings when attempting this in the category.

There is further excellent discussion of this here: [Is calling super in a category the same as calling it in a subclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168058/is-calling-super-in-a-category-the-same-as-calling-it-in-a-subclass/6170660#6170660)

Comment: It should also be noted that using a category to override methods of framework classes is almost certainly a bad idea. _Every instance_ of the class uses the overridden method, whether created by you or something else.