# Why [super class] and [self class] produce the same result?

Tags: objective-c

```
-(NSString *) nibName
{
    PO([self class]);
    PO([super class]);
    PO([self superclass]);
```

Only the `[self superclass]` produces the actual super class.

```
[self class]: BGImageForBizs
[super class]: BGImageForBizs
[self superclass]: BGUIImageWithActivityIndicator
```

Comment: I don't know Obj-C, but that smells like virtual methods to me

Comment: See also: [Is calling super in a category the same as calling it in a subclass?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6168058)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sending a message using `super` is the same as sending it to `self`, but explicitly uses the superclass' method implementation. But your class probably doesn't implement the `-class` method itself, so you're already inheriting the implementation of `-class` from your superclass already.

In fact, you're probably inheriting `NSObject`'s implementation of `-class` (even if `NSObject` isn't your immediate superclass; `-class` isn't a method that gets overriden often). And the default implementation just returns the contents of the object's `isa` pointer, telling you what `Class` it is.

In other words, it's important to recognize that calling `super` doesn't completely transform your object into an instance of its superclass; it just runs the superclass' code for that method. If there's any introspection going on in that code, it still sees your object as an instance of whatever class it started out as.

Answer (score 9):

self and super are the same object. The only thing super does is control which implementation of the method is called. Since both your class and the superclass are using NSObject's implementation of -class, the same method is called in both cases.

Comment: Argh, 11 minutes too slow! This is what I get for answering questions from my iPhone. Good first answer. :)