# iOS 7 : Disable UINavigationBar Translucency For Entire App

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, ios7

Is there a way to disable UINavigationBar Translucency for an entire application?

I'm aware that using `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO]` can fix this issue for a single controller, but I have a lot of UINavigationBars in my application and this is a pretty tedious solution.

I've tried `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO]`, but that functionality is surprisingly not supported.  Doing that results in `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** Illegal property type, c for appearance setter, _installAppearanceSwizzlesForSetter:'`

If I HAVE to, I can go through my entire app setting UINavigationBars to disable translucency one by one, but there must be some more elegant solution to this issue...

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not.

Comment: Better yet, is there a way to force my views to layout in a sane manner without needing to turn the translucency off? This is ridiculous

Answer (score 33, accepted):

if you set the translucence of the first navigation bar in the stack to `false` `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO]`, it will reflect in all the following NavigationViewController that are pushed to that stack.

Comment: If you are using the storyboard, deselect transparency from UINavigationController.

Comment: This solution is not complete if you display any modal view controllers or anything that does not occur within the navigation controller.

Answer (score 19):

Here is a Swift solution if you want to apply this Styling to the whole app.

in the `AppDelegate` class add this to the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

**For Swift 2:**

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
```

**For Swift 3+:**

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

Answer (score 8):

It seems very simple with this code in `appDelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` (works fine with iOS 8 and above versions)

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
```

Comment: I'm not sure why someone gave this a negative score, I used this and worked perfectly! I've voted it up!

Comment: Definitely maybe! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are right about no appearance proxy being available for this property. Are you using UINavigationControllers or UINavigationBar objects? If you are using UINavigationBars you could subclass it and create a non-translucent nav bar.

Header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ABCNonTranslucentNavBar : UINavigationBar

@end
```

Implementation file:

```
#import "ABCNonTranslucentNavBar.h"

@implementation ABCNonTranslucentNavBar

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  [self setTranslucent:NO];
}
```

Then just replace the UINavigationBars with your subclass. You could also do something similar with a subclassed UINavigationController.

Comment: That is definitely an interesting idea, but a bit of a pain.  Maybe there is an easier way...?  Regardless of the answer to this question as of right now, I would be shocked if iOS 7.1 doesn't add a translucency appearance proxy.  Also, to answer your question, I am using UINavigationControllers, not just the bar.

Comment: How about using method swizzle and just patch it on viewDidLoad?

Comment: You can also subclass UINavigationController and override the designated initializer to set self.navigationBar.translucent = NO

Comment: Doing this is -drawRect:... Have fun watching your app break ;)

Answer (score 3):

Adding this in case anyones still battling this.

You can fool it though by specifying a non exist image, which will make the nav bar INCLUDING it's tool bar go opaque

```
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:219.0/255.0 green:67.0/255.0 blue:67.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forToolbarPosition:UIBarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: when applying this to the uinavigationbar you will end up with a black statusbar :(

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but this might come in handy for someone;

You can use a category, and within it* set the property `[translucent][1]`

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (MakeTranslucent)

-(void)willMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)newWindow {
    [super willMoveToWindow:newWindow];


    self.translucent = NO;
}
@end
```

- I used willMoveToWindow, I do not know whether this is a good idea so UAYOR.

Comment: Note that this is dangerous, as it will not call the original UINavigationBar implementation of `willMoveToWindow:`. The category method replaces the original implementation of the method entirely, so you're actually skipping the original UINavigationBar implementation and calling UIView's implementation directly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168058/is-calling-super-in-a-category-the-same-as-calling-it-in-a-subclass

Comment: Its a terrible idea to override methods using categories. In fact, in iOS 8.3 it seems the category methods which override class methods will not be called.

Answer (score 1):

See the excerpt from UIKit code documentation:

```
/*
     New behavior on iOS 7.
     Default is YES.
     You may force an opaque background by setting the property to NO.
     If the navigation bar has a custom background image, the default is inferred 
     from the alpha values of the image—YES if it has any pixel with alpha < 1.0
     If you send setTranslucent:YES to a bar with an opaque custom background image
     it will apply a system opacity less than 1.0 to the image.
     If you send setTranslucent:NO to a bar with a translucent custom background image
     it will provide an opaque background for the image using the bar's barTintColor if defined, or black
     for UIBarStyleBlack or white for UIBarStyleDefault if barTintColor is nil.
     */
```

**Correct Swift 4 solution is**

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .white
```

Answer (score 0):

I think appearance api does not support translucent property of navigation bar .
But you can do this for whole App like this , please have a look at this code --

here Menu Screen is a root view controller .

```
MenuScreen *ms = [[MenuScreen alloc]initWithNibName:@"MenuScreen" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *nv = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:ms];

//This will set property for whole App.
[nv.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];

self.window.rootViewController = nv ;
```

Comment: It will only set it to translucent for this one navigation stack. If you have any modal navigation controllers, multiple tabs or any other kind of more complex navigation patterns, it won't work.

Comment: so you have to set each and every stack by like this

Comment: Yes, sure. But the point of this question was if there is a way to set it *globally* (like via `UIAppearance`), and that's exactly not what you're doing. Moreover, you're saying in your answer that it "will be set for the whole app", which is not true.

Answer (score -3):

If you don't use storyboard, but IB, set the navigation bar style of your MainWindows.xib to NOT translucent and set as color not the clear color.