# Set navigation bars to translucent: NO

Tags: ios, transparent, navbar

How can I set all my navigation bars to have their `translucent` property set to `NO`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 7 : Disable UINavigationBar Translucency For Entire App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883301/ios-7-disable-uinavigationbar-translucency-for-entire-app)

Answer (score 10):

Code:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
```